# Prove that if one function is greater or equal than another, then so it is its limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Let $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ be real functions such that $f(x) \le g(x);  \forall x$ such that both $f$ and $g$ are defined. Using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit show that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \le \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$, given that both are defined.

---

Here's my solution:

Let's assume the contrary, so let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = M$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = N$, such that $M>N$. Now using the condition we have:

$$f(x) + N < g(x) + M: \quad \quad \forall x \in D_f \text{ and } x \in D_g$$
$$f(x) - M < g(x) - N; \quad \quad \forall x \in D_f \text{ and } x \in D_g$$

Hence there always exists $\epsilon$ such that $\mid f(x) - M \mid < \epsilon  <\mid  g(x) - N \mid$ or $\mid f(x) - M \mid > \epsilon  > \mid  g(x) - N \mid$, since the set of reals is dense and we don't have equality.

Hence for this $\epsilon$ we're not able to find $\delta$ such that:

$$0<\mid x-a \mid < \delta \implies \mid f(x) - M \mid < \epsilon \quad \text{or} \quad 0<\mid x-a \mid < \delta \implies \mid g(x) - N \mid < \epsilon$$

which means that one of the limits is wrong which isn't possible. Hence $M\le N$. Q.E.D.

---

I think this proof is alright, but is it possible to prove the statement without the initial assumption, or at least without using the fact that the set of reals is dense?

Comment: I am inclined to say this proof is false. If $x\to a$ then both $\vert f(x)-M\vert\to0 $ and $\vert g(x)-N\vert\to0$. This would mean that $ \vert f(x) - M \vert < \epsilon  <\vert  g(x) - N \vert$ does not hold when $x\to a$. N.B. In general it is not uncommon for < or > to change into $\leq$ or $\geq$, respectively when taking limits.

Comment: @gebruiker To get that statement we don't use limits at all. I mean $|f(x)-M| < |g(x) - N|$ or $|g(x) - N| < |f(x)-M|$ is true solely due to the fact that $M>N$ and $g(x)\ge f(x)$.

Comment: But when $x\to a$, $\vert f(x)-M\vert = \vert g(x)-N\vert$...

Comment: @gebruiker The fact that I mentioned is true for every $x$ in every $\delta$-neighbourhood of $a$, assuming that $M>N$ and $g(x) \ge f(x)$. But as you notice we later find that it can't hold, since otherwise one of the limits is wrong, hence ours assumption is wrong, i.e. $M\ge N$

Comment: Not it is not. It fails for $x=a$ for example (when $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$).

Comment: Unrelated to your question: I believe one is "supposed" to typ `\vert a \vert` to get $\vert a \vert$. I noticed you used `\mid a \mid`.

Comment: Yes and we use that fact that it fails in some $\delta$-neighbourhood of $a$ to derive the contradiction.

Comment: @gebruiker Imagine this. Let $a<b$ and $c\le d$. Then $a+c < b+d \implies a-d<b-c$. This is through for any real numbers under the assumption. Now replace $a=f(x), b=g(x), d=M and c=N$. But given that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = M$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = N$ that is wrong, which means that the assumption can must be wrong.

Comment: Your last example does not hold. If you would choose $a=f(x)$ and $b=g(x)$ the initial assumtion would be $f(x)<g(x)$, which is not the case. I'll try to elaborate in my answer. Editing now....

Comment: @gebruiker I'm sorry choose $a=N, d=M, c=f(x), d=g(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't check your proof, but here is a much easier way to prove your result.

Let $$L_1:=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad L_2=\lim_{x\to a}g(x).$$
Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence that converges to $a$. For all $n$ we have, $$ f(x_n)\leq g(x_n),$$ and thus $$L_1=\lim_{n\to\infty }f(x_n)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty }g(x_n)=L_2,$$
which proves the claim.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I can't use this sequence stuffs. Also as the problem says I should prove it using only the formal $\delta$ - $\epsilon$ proof.

Comment: You can easily adapt this proof as an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof ;-)

Comment: I will give it a shot

Comment: @Downvoter: Could you explain ?

Answer (score 3):

Repeating what I said in the comments: I am inclined to say this proof is false. If $x\to a$ then both $\vert f(x)-M\vert\to0 $ and $\vert g(x)-N\vert\to0$. This would mean that $ \vert f(x) - M \vert < \epsilon  <\vert  g(x) - N \vert$ does not hold when $x\to a$. Your proof does not hold, because the epsilon you choose is **nonexistent** for certain values of $x$ (in particular for the values we're interested in). We cannot come to a contradiction off something  nonexistent. This is as clear as I can formulate it.

N.B. In general it is not uncommon for < or > to change into $\leq$ or $\geq$, respectively when taking limits.

---

Here's an example of a proof:

We have  $f(x)\leq g(x)$ and  $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=M$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)=N$. Now assume that $M > N$. The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition can be rephrased to say:

> If $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=M$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $f(a-\delta;a+\delta)\subseteq (M-\epsilon; M+\epsilon)$.

And of course the same holds for $g(x)$ and $N$.

Now  they say we may take **any** $\epsilon>0$, so we might as well take $\epsilon =\frac{M-N}{2}$. Now according to the definition there is a  $\delta$ (convince yourself that one $\delta $ suffices) such that \begin{gather}f(a-\delta;a+\delta)\subseteq (M-\epsilon;M+\epsilon)
\\\text{and}\\ 
g(a-\delta;a+\delta)\subseteq (N-\epsilon;N+\epsilon).\end{gather}

Now note that all numbers in $(M-\epsilon;M+\epsilon)$ are strictly greater than all numbers in $(N-\epsilon;N+\epsilon)$. This means that any $x\in(a-\delta;a+\delta)$ violates $f(x)\leq g(x)$, giving the sought for contradiction. Hence $M\leq N$.

Comment: I think that the solution is right, but again can't understand what's wrong with my proof.$ |g(x) - N| \not= |f(x) - M|$ under the initial assumption. But later we prove that if $N$ and $M$ are the values of the limit then this can't be true, hence the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely have to apply the density property, how else will you be able to justify that if $a<b$ then there exists $c$ such that $a<c<b$

Counter example:
Let $f(x)\equiv M, g(x)\equiv N$ be constant functions. Then $|f(x)-M|<|g(x)-N|$ is violated.

Comment: Hence the assumption $M>N$ is wrong. Using the assumption we get that one of $|f(x)-M| > |g(x)-N|$ or $|g(x)-N| > |f(x)-M|$ holds, which is not possible.

Comment: But you have established right after fixing $M>N$ that $f(x)-M < g(x)-N$. In other words $0<0$. Let's assume, you fixed that part.

Further down the road you say that if we fix $\varepsilon >0$ we cannot determine a $\delta >0$ such that so and so.
Both limits use the same $\delta$ for our fixed $\varepsilon$, which loses generality.

Comment: $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not fixed. Maybe you can read my discussion with @gebruikler in the comments.